# How to set country location and other variables to a cookie with php

Tags: php, setcookie

I want to set a cookie with the country name and city location but I am unable as we had to set cookies before anything.  How can I set my variables to its value?

```
include_once('ip2locationlite.class.php');
$ipLite = new ip2location_lite;
$ipLite->setKey('d930e8b9b1a38e8f647a5f22cce63e18a414e99aaf329a9f38a6caf8f623ec31');
$locations = $ipLite->getCity($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$errors = $ipLite->getError();
$values="";
if (!empty($locations) && is_array($locations)) {
echo $locations['ipAddress'];
echo $locations['countryName'];
echo $locations['regionName'];
echo $locations['cityName'];
$values="ipaddress : ".$locations['ipAddress']."<br>country : ".$locations['countryName']."<br>region : ".$locations['regionName']."<br> city :".$locations['cityName'];

}

if(!isset($_COOKIE['trakcer']))
{
    setcookie('trakcer',$values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\you are using wrong way to  set cookie, try:

```
if (!empty($locations) && is_array($locations)) {
$values = serialize($location); //serialize you array
//then set cookie
 if(!isset($_COOKIE['trakcer'])) {
   setcookie("CookieName", $values, time()+3600);  /* expires in 1 hour */
 }
}
//and to get it
$array = unserialize($_COOKIE['CookieName']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do any echo or print before setcookie. Cookie can be set when no other headers were set/send.

Read documentation for more information [php.net/setcookie](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)